# detecting the current build type of a project programmatically

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My Android project is using gradle build:

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            ...
        }

        release {
           ...
        }
    }

buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
        }
        release {
          ...
        }
 }
```

I am wondering is there a way to detect the current build type in Java code of Android project? How to achieve this?

Comment: BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are BuildConfig class in your project that contains app id, build type, flavors and other.

Comment: Where can I find the official documentation for it? I can't find in developer site.

Comment: There are no official documentation but there https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html#simplify-app-development you may find how to insert custom fields into BuildConfig.